# PostgreSQL query to array of arrays, list of lists or tuple of tuples

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,'adam',),(2,'eve')
```

I'm trying to save foo into a table, as a list of lists or something similar.
I know I can save it using ´SELECT json_agg(foo)´ but my queries return too much data so I do not want to waste space with the keys (column names)
Instead of:

```
{{"id":1,"name":"adam"},{"id":2,"name":"Eve"}}
```

I would like an elegant way my query to return

```
[[1,"adam"],[2,"eve"]]
```

Also, I need an elegant way of querying this data back as a table. (I know the name of the columns, so I don't need the keys that are returned by json_agg

Comment: Would be ok to cast your id into text? You cannot create an array with multiple data types: `SELECT array_agg(ARRAY[id::TEXT,name]) FROM foo;`

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the column names because I'm building a function... But it'd be the same with `SELECT array_agg(foo) FROM foo;` as Gordon said below. The problem now is... How can I come back from this array_agg to the table? Assuming that I know the column names

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, an array can contain a record.  So you can simply use:

```
select array_agg(foo)
from foo;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6f2417295a6a0ee882d6d7f8911370c1) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem now is... How can I come back from this array_agg to the table? Assuming that I know the column names

Comment: @NicolásRivera . . . (1) I don't understand your comment, unless you are referring to `unnest()`.  (2) This answers the question you asked here and a new question should be asked as a *new* question.